# Tizen-sdk-for-wearable-setup Installation issue because of JAVA HOME

Tags: windows, tizen, java-home, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-install

System Configuration:

```
OS - Windows 8
System type - 64-bit Operating System , x64-based processor
```

I have installed java-8 and set JAVA_HOME as

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
```

I am getting error as below image while Tizen-sdk-for-wearable-setup Installation.

[image: Tizen Installation error]

**error** - `Cannot execute Java even if it was installed. Check environment variable or Java version(over 1.6) please.`

I tried installing after JDK 7 both 32 bit and 64 bit and setting `JAVA_HOME` - `Program Files path` and `Program Files (x86) path` both also it didn't worked.

I have a another system in which the Issue didn't occurred.

System Configuration :

```
OS - Windows 7 Enterprise
System Type - 32 bit operating system.
```

Installed Java - `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`

JAVA_HOME set as - `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`

Now there may be many chances why installation is not getting in my win-8 64 bit.

1. 64 bit JAVA support is not available.
2. I am not sure about `~` symbol in `JAVA_HOME` path but it may be to escape space between Program Files and I have not set java home using this symbol.
3. In win-8 64 bit I have 2 folders. Program Files and Program Files (x86) , I am not sure whether to use `~` or `" "` to set `JAVA_HOME` and for `32 bit java` or `64 bit java` installed.
4. May be only java 1.6 is supported right now.

I searched and found similar issues :

1. I find [this link](http://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/cant-install-sdk-windows-64) but not able to get why its advised to set the system environment Path Variable to 'c:\windows\system32'.
2. In [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/installation-failure-windows-8) its advised to use InstallManager.jar via cmd.exe.

I can try each possible assumption till it works but hoping to find a solution with proper reason why I am getting this error.

If any one knows how should I work this out please help.

Comment: You can get the short 8.3 filename by opening a terminal (cmd), navigating to `c:` and executing `dir Program* /x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last solve the Issue.

Installed `jdk1.7.0_51` (I think currently JAVA 8 is not supported).

Set the `JAVA_HOME` as `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51` (thanks to @Michael comment).

Comment: I have it this way and it still complains :/

Comment: I solved putting this C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin in the PATH but before another entry for jre8...

Answer (score 2):

This link: https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/16878/cant-install-tizen-sdk-on-windows-8-64-bit.html solved for me the problem of Tizen SDK installation:

Change directory to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\tizensdk_TimeStampOfInstallationInvocation

java -jar InstallManager.jar

My system: Windows 7 Ultimate x64. Java's version installed (64 bit):

g:>echo %JAVA_HOME%

c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

g:>echo %CLASSPATH%

c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib

Added to PATH: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\

(Tizen IDE and "Hello World" example run just fine.)

Comment: To verify the java you can use the following command to check the java version:

       "javac -version"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and finally I realised that my version of Tizen installer is 64bit but I installed 32bit java in my computer. Then I downloaded 32bit Tizen installer and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and it was solved by placing the Java path in the beginning of the system path ! weird.. but worked :)

Comment: No - a restart wasn't needed - as the path modifications are real time. However, it was strange that I had to keep the java path at the beginning of the PATH variable - guess otherwise I had a conflict with the paths...

Answer (score 0):

You must include, depending on whether you downloaded the x86 or x64 Tizen installer, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin` or `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` in the `PATH` environment system variable.  You **can't** use java 8.  See [this oracle page](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) for instructions on setting environment variables.  I have read some others mention that they put the entry at the very beginning of the PATH variable.  I think this would only matter if you also had an entry for java 8, but better safe than sorry.