# Installing tizen in windows 7

Tags: java, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying to install tizen wearable sdk in windows 7 64bit. I have donwload the .exe however when I am trying to isntall it I am getting the following error:

```
error - Cannot execute Java even if it was installed. Check environment variable or Java version(over 1.6) please.
```

I have installed in my computer java 1.7.0_80. I have put to the path of the system `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` and in JAVA_HOME `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80`

I have tried to follow the instructions from here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627553/tizen-sdk-for-wearable-setup-installation-issue-because-of-java-home)  however I didn't mange to solve my issues.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I followed the instructions from that [link](https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/16878/cant-install-tizen-sdk-on-windows-8-64-bit.html) I went to cd\Users\AppData\Local\Temp and I run from there the command in console java -jar installmanager.jar. THe installation began normally. However, during the installation I got several errors.

Comment: If you open a command prompt and type "java -version", what is the output? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: java -version 1.7.0_80 and javac -version javac 1.7.0_80

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? It really looks like a PATH issue and Windows is sometimes a bit weird about its path. Rebooting usually fixes things.

Comment: Nope I got the same message.

Comment: I was also having the installation issue sometimes back while installing 64 bit sdk. I uninstalled 64bit java and re-installed it and then I was able to install 64 bit sdk without any error. Also remove all tizen-sdk (sdk and data) folders if any available in your installation directory if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a few problems with the Tizen Wearable install too.

1. You can either make sure that you have Java in your path by going to a command prompt and typing `java -version` for example. If it works then Java is in your path. If it doesn't you have to fix it:

   - Win+Pause/SysRq then click on Advanced System Settings
   - Click on environment variables
   - Look for PATH and edit it
   - Add the path to your Java install (eg: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31)
2. Or run from the command line:

   - Go to a command line
   - cd to %TEMP%
   - Run Java by first entering the path to your java version (eg C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31) then bin\java, so C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe

If you are still having problems then edit the question to add more specific information so any other issues can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if this directory is in the path too:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

and if there is links to missing java executables.
If this is the case, you can remove that folder to the path, replacing with the current java version you want, or fix the link from there.

Comment: Ok indeed that dir you mention is in my path. Should I remove this dir from the path?

Comment: @JoseRamon check the links inside, then repair if they are pointing missing files

Comment: They are pointing to 1.8 version of java which is different from the version I have in the path. I cant change their pointing location.

Comment: @JoseRamon remove that directory from the path and live yours.

Comment: In this dir I have 3 shortcuts that pointing to java.exe javaw and javaws.exe. I have already remove C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath from my path. However I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the VBS script tried to delete a file that doesn't exist, you can go to the VBS file and go to the problem line, and check out which file was missing. Then decide what to do.

Maybe you should install the latest JDK, try the latest JDK and see if the problem can be solved.