# Tizen Install on Windows 10 will not recognize JDK 9 installed

Tags: java, windows, sdk, installation, tizen

I am attempting to install the 64-bit version of Tizen SDK on my Win10 Home Laptop. However, every time I get the error that I either don't have java 8+ installed or that the JAVA_HOME environmental variable isn't set right.

Now I've read other questions on this, and I've set the JDK directory as first in the "Path" environmental variable. I've added the JAVA_HOME environ. var and pointed it at my JDK directory. I've rebooted twice throughout this (just in case).

I tried to install the 32-bit version of Tizen SDK, but immediately got the error that I'm not on a 32-bit OS.

I have d/l and installed Java 9 SDK and JRE. They're in 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9 &
C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9 respectively.

Here's my Path variable:
[Path Variable Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1WrJ.png)

Any help would be mucho appreciated!

Comment: Edited my response

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Response on Oct, 2017:***

** **So far Tizen studio installer can't recognize new version of Java.** **
You need to install Oracle Java 8 for now.

Additional Checklist:

[✔]  Tizen developers site states "Do **not** install **OpenJDK**". Make sure you are using **OracleJDK** instead of OpenJDK. Related links you might see:

[Forum Post](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/ubuntu-16.04-ide-2.4-rev6-install-no-jdk)

[✔] There's a Tip&Tech document on Tizen Developers 
Community called 'Guide for Setting JDK'. As you are having Issues, You may check it out.

[Tizen: Guide for Setting JDK](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/guide-setting-jdk)

[✔] I expect you are using the Latest Tizen Studio 2.0.

[Latest Tizen Studio Download Link](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download)

Cause history says, Java compatibility Defers with IDE versions:
[Tizen-sdk-for-wearable-setup Installation issue because of JAVA HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627553/tizen-sdk-for-wearable-setup-installation-issue-because-of-java-home)

***Edit on March, 2019:***

Tizen-Studio now supports OpenJDK 10

To use Tizen Studio install Oracle Java Development Kit (JDK) 8, JDK 9, or OpenJDK 10 .

Prerequisites for the Tizen Studio
[OpenJDK 10 and OpenJFX Installation Guideline on Tizen Developers Site](https://developer.tizen.org/development/articles/openjdk-10-and-openjfx-installation-guide)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize about the OpenJDK vs. OracleJDK.

Comment: Ps. The documentation's a bit misleading for Windows.  You need to point `JAVA_HOME` at the `bin` sub-directory (containing `java.exe`), and then add `%JAVA_HOME%` to the `Path` variable.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Your comment (bin in JAVA_HOME and PATH) should be the accepted answer. Thx.

Comment: Last link is broken (of course). Someone tell Samsung that moving doc pages around the site is stupid.

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck there for a while, too. In addition to setting `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1` (no `bin` at the end), I also added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin` to the beginning of `PATH`; then it worked.

Comment: wow this was it, this fixed it for me (specifically removing /bin from JAVA_HOME)

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem, therefore i installed JDK8 from oracle website and the installer works fine. (no need to reboot) If you don't need specific JDK9 stuff, go with 8 and you will be good to go. Don't forget to update JAVA_HOME and Path to point to JDK8.

I have set as user variables CLASSPATH set to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib, JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144

As system variables i've added to the existing Path this value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin and JAVA_HOME the same as above (even though i'm not sure the latter one is required).

PS. I have both JDK8 and 9 installed and Windows 10 64bit. I tried installing Tizen on debian using JDK9 and i got the same error, i'm sure that using JDK8 will work (need to check installation on OSX though)

Cheers!

Comment: This issue still persists. I cannot find a means of downloading Java 8 or 9 as it has reached it's end of life and can no longer be downloaded. Does anyone have a link to a Java 8 or 9 direct download?

Answer (score 2):

On my M1 Mac with macOS 12, I was having trouble getting the Tizen package manager to run. It kept giving me:

```
Java Development Kit (JDK) was not found on your computer. To use the Tizen Studio, you need to install the JDK 8 or later. Please go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads and download a JDK.
```

Deleting `~/.package-manager` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin" (with the quotes) to the PATH did the trick, i.e. the installer run successfully

Answer (score 0):

Information on [the tizen website](https://developer.tizen.org/development/articles/openjdk-10-and-openjfx-installation-guide) is incomplete. On Windows 10 using OpenJDK follow the article and you need to enter another environment and system parameters after adding Java_home.
Parameter is "PATH"  value is "%JAVA_HOME%\bin" otherwise Tizen Studio installation wont recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I download the IDE of `version 3.2` and install the `open jdk10`, IDE can load successfully, but load the emulator failed when click the tools -> emulator manager.

> error: could not create the java virtual machine.

**my setting**:
**path:** %JAVA_HOME%\bin
**JAVA_PATH:** c\jdk-10

what's the problem here? please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me in the end was:

- Uninstall the recent Java version and install Java SE 8u231.
- After that, I tried Tizen 1.3, and it worked.

I don't know if the newer versions works, but the above worked for me for now.